# sql server 2008 deleting duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have duplicates like this

```
col1, col2
1, alex
1, alex
2, liza
2, liza
3, peter
3, peter
```

there are only two of each. how do i delete the duplicates?

Comment: Are there any other columns available to distinguish between the rows?

Comment: @joeyes there's a sequential pK

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: @Martin: "how to delete duplicates" seems to be the most duplicate question ever.

Comment: Lol! Maybe the OP was just being ironic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1, col2) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
DELETE
FROM    q
WHERE   rn >= 2
```

See here:

- [**Deleting duplicates**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/14/deleting-duplicates/)

Comment: +1: Learned something new. I didn't know you could use a CTE as the target of a delete operation.

Answer (score 1):

If the origin table is not huge.

```
select distinct * from origin_table into temp_table;
truncate table origin_table;
insert into origin_table select * from temp_table ;
drop table temp_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table_new
   Select col1, col2, min(pk) as pk from table_old
   group by col1, col2

-- debug table_new

drop table_old
```